# How do I Use Rest Template with the Spring Boot CLI?

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following code...

```
@Grab(
    group='org.springframework', 
    module='spring-web', 
    version='5.0.4.RELEASE'
)
@RestController
public class MainEndpoint{
    @GetMapping("/")
    String home() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getForObject(
            "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/3725.txt.utf-8", 
            String.class
        )
    }
}
```

But when I run this I get

Output:

```
unable to resolve class RestTemplate
```

Do I need an import or something? I thought SpringBoot handled all that in the background.

How do I use RestTemplate with the spring Boot Cli?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the import.

The below snippet Groovy but its ports to Java with little or no change.

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController 

class MyController{

    @GetMapping("/")
    String home() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(
            "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/3725.txt.utf-8", 
            String.class
        )
        return result;
    }
}
```